# Upgrading Entity Framework 1 to version 4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Are there any gothcas or problems when upgrading Entity Framework 1 to version 4 (or 4.1)?

Note: We can't switch to something else. The current project needs to stay EF-based.

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading from EFv1 to EFv4 you will just open your project in VS2010 and your EDMX file should be upgraded automatically. Once you have any problem after the upgrade ask separate question for that particular problem.

Upgrading from EFv1 to EFv4.1 starts in similar way - you will upgrade to EFv4 and after that you will change code generation strategy from default custom tool to DbContext T4 generator. It will definitely break all your code using EF because you will change ObjectContext API to DbContext API with completely different public interface. There is not automatic way to upgrade your code from ObjecContext API to DbContext API.